# Ruby on Rails: Create an Activity Feed by Sum two Model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create an activity feed mixing two models (Post + Like). Activity feed show both current user and following users Post + Like.

I create feed method in the User model (following the MHartl Tutorial).

```
  def feed

    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    Posts = Post.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
    Likes = Like.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)

    Posts + Likes

  end
```

Than in controller I simply call `@feed = current_user.feed.paginate` etc... And all works properly.

Is it correct to sum Posts and Likes in this way?

Comment: Surely it's incorrect to use constants in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would try get the most from Rails models.

For example, `following_ids` could be returned by a scope or a class method of Relationship:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :followed_ids, ->(user_id) { where(follower_id: user_id).pluck(:followed_id) }
  # or

  def self.followed_ids(user_id)
    where(follower_id: user_id).pluck(:followed_id)
  end
end
```

You can basically do the same thing for Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :feed_for, ->(user_id, following_ids) { where(user_id: [user_id, *following_ids]) }
end
```

and Like:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :feed_for, ->(user_id, following_ids) { where(user_id: [user_id, *following_ids]) }
end
```

And finally integrate it into your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def feed
    following_ids = Relationship.followed_ids(self.id)
    Post.feed_for(self.id, following_ids) + Like.feed_for(self.id, following_ids)
  end

end
```

Try to not use raw sql inside your Rails code and to delegate the responsibility of every action to the most relevant model for it.